# Unable to connect to secure hbase cluster using phoenix

Tags: security, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am facing issues in connecting to secure `hbase` cluster using `Phoenix 4.3.0` and `CDH5.4.3`. I am running a Java program for testing connection to secure cluster. I am using following format of connection string with `PhoenixDriver`:

`jdbc:phoenix:[quorom]:[port]:[rootNode]:[principal]:[keytab]`

I have put followings in the classpath:

```
core-site.xml
hbase-site.xml
phoenix-client-cloudera-4.3.0.jar 
zookeeper-cloudera-3.4.5.jar
```

I am unable to connect to secure cluster. Stack trace of the exceptions is given below. It is trying to connect to cluster using simple authentication and not using Kerberos/SASL authentication. Also, HADOOP_HOME is not set. Where should I set this env variable?

As I am using one phoenix jar containing all required jars, is it right way or should I use phoenix-without-hbase.jar?

> 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess
>   with annotation
>   @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(value=[Rate of
>   successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=,
>   valueName=Time, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops) 15/08/25
>   23:04:47 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure
>   with annotation
>   @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(value=[Rate of failed
>   kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, valueName=Time,
>   type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops) 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups
>   with annotation
>   @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(value=[GetGroups],
>   about=, valueName=Time, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
>   15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and
>   group related metrics 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG security.Groups: 
>   Creating new Groups object 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   util.NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop
>   library... 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Failed to
>   load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   hadoop in java.library.path 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   util.NativeCodeLoader:
>   java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib 15/08/25
>   23:04:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping
>   impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping 15/08/25
>   23:04:47 DEBUG util.Shell: Failed to detect a valid hadoop home
>   directory java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not
>   set.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:302)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:327)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.(StringUtils.java:79)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:86)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:66)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:311)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:276)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$300(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:166)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$11.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1831)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$11.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1810)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1810)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:126)
>           at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
>   15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG util.Shell: setsid exited with exit code 0
>   15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG security.Groups: Group mapping
>   impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback;
>   cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit 15/08/25 23:04:47
>   DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal:
>   admin 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: Using
>   user: "UnixPrincipal: admin" with name admin 15/08/25 23:04:47 DEBUG
>   security.UserGroupInformation: User entry: "admin" 15/08/25 23:04:47
>   DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:admin (auth:SIMPLE)
>
> 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG util.MBeans: Registered
>   Hadoop:service=phoenix,name=MetricsSystem,sub=Stats 15/08/25 23:04:48
>   DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source
>   MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered. 15/08/25 23:04:48 INFO
>   impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: phoenix metrics system
>   started 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsConfig: poking parent
>   'PropertiesConfiguration' for key: source.source.start_mbeans 15/08/25
>   23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsConfig: poking parent 'MetricsConfig' for
>   key: source.start_mbeans 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsConfig:
>   poking parent 'PropertiesConfiguration' for key: *.source.start_mbeans
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: Updating attr
>   cache... 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: Done. #
>   tags & metrics=8 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter:
>   Updating info cache... 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl:
>   [javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Metrics context,
>   name=tag.Context, type=java.lang.String, read-only, descriptor={}],
>   javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Local hostname,
>   name=tag.Hostname, type=java.lang.String, read-only, descriptor={}],
>   javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Number of ops for rate
>   of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds),
>   name=LoginSuccessNumOps, type=java.lang.Long, read-only,
>   descriptor={}],
>   javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Average time for rate
>   of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds),
>   name=LoginSuccessAvgTime, type=java.lang.Double, read-only,
>   descriptor={}], javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Number
>   of ops for rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds),
>   name=LoginFailureNumOps, type=java.lang.Long, read-only,
>   descriptor={}],
>   javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Average time for rate
>   of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds),
>   name=LoginFailureAvgTime, type=java.lang.Double, read-only,
>   descriptor={}], javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Number
>   of ops for getGroups, name=GetGroupsNumOps, type=java.lang.Long,
>   read-only, descriptor={}],
>   javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Average time for
>   getGroups, name=GetGroupsAvgTime, type=java.lang.Double, read-only,
>   descriptor={}]] 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter:
>   Done 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG util.MBeans: Registered
>   Hadoop:service=phoenix,name=UgiMetrics 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG
>   impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source UgiMetrics registered.
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Registered source
>   UgiMetrics 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG util.MBeans: Registered
>   Hadoop:service=phoenix,name=MetricsSystem,sub=Control 15/08/25
>   23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: tracing, Phoenix call tracing
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsConfig: poking parent
>   'PropertiesConfiguration' for key: source.source.start_mbeans 15/08/25
>   23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsConfig: poking parent 'MetricsConfig' for
>   key: source.start_mbeans 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsConfig:
>   poking parent 'PropertiesConfiguration' for key: *.source.start_mbeans
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: Updating attr
>   cache... 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: Done. #
>   tags & metrics=2 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter:
>   Updating info cache... 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl:
>   [javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=num spans,
>   name=tag.stat, type=java.lang.String, read-only, descriptor={}],
>   javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo[description=Local hostname,
>   name=tag.Hostname, type=java.lang.String, read-only, descriptor={}]]
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: Done 15/08/25
>   23:04:48 DEBUG util.MBeans: Registered
>   Hadoop:service=phoenix,name=tracing 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG
>   impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source tracing registered.
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Registered source
>   tracing 15/08/25 23:04:48 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
>   15/08/25 23:04:48 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process
>   identifier=hconnection-0x118d1f9 connecting to ZooKeeper
>   ensemble=csc-hdp-sa-********:2181 15/08/25 23:04:48 DEBUG
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x118d1f90x0,
>   quorum=csc-hdp-sa-********:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received ZooKeeper
>   Event, type=None, state=SyncConnected, path=null 15/08/25 23:04:48
>   DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient:
>   Codec=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.codec.KeyValueCodec@6bed5,
>   compressor=null, tcpKeepAlive=true, tcpNoDelay=true, connectTO=10000,
>   readTO=20000, writeTO=60000, minIdleTimeBeforeClose=120000,
>   maxRetries=0, fallbackAllowed=false, bind address=null 15/08/25
>   23:04:48 DEBUG zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher:
>   hconnection-0x118d1f9-0x24f678271a30191 connected 15/08/25 23:04:49
>   DEBUG ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service
>   MasterService, sasl=false 15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to
>   csc-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000 15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service
>   MasterService, sasl=false 15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to
>   csc-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000 15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service
>   MasterService, sasl=false 15/08/25 23:04:49 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to
>   csc-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000 15/08/25 23:04:50 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service
>   MasterService, sasl=false 15/08/25 23:04:50 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to
>   csc-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000 15/08/25 23:04:51 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service
>   MasterService, sasl=false 15/08/25 23:04:51 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to
>   csc-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000 15/08/25 23:04:53 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service
>   MasterService, sasl=false 15/08/25 23:04:53 DEBUG
>   ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to
>   csc-hdp-sa-********/10.99.40.213:60000

Comment: i think you should first try to connect to Phoenix 'by hand', via something like: # ./sqlline.py localhost